# Can a nessus scan running on top of a Windows OS do full internal scans of devices using ssh?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, nessus

I am wondering if I did a Nessus scan using a Windows machine how it would log in to a Linux based device.

Windows does not have a native ssh client.  I am aware that Nessus will log into systems given credentials and scan from the inside out.  Does Nessus install a ssh client or does it simply do external scan?

I am particularly wondering about Linux variant devices such as CISCO switches.  In an ideal environment http and telnet admin are turned off to reduce the attack area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cisco devices use IOS, and they have the ability to accept ssh connections. Nessus is an ssh client and can perform scans externally as well as by logging in, if the credentials are supplied. It makes no difference if there is an ssh client installed on the server it is being run from.